# Problem with a particular MD file being ignored in rendered pandoc output

Tags: html, rendering, pandoc, documentation-generation

I'm using pandoc to generate my thesis from Markdown to HTML/PDF/DOCX.

I'm having a problem with the HTML generation, one chapter is being missed out of the rendered HTML output.

Here is my command:

```
pandoc src/index.md src/frontmatter.md src/chapter-1.md src/chapter-2.md src/chapter-3.md src/chapter-4.md src/chapter-5.md src/bibliography.md --toc --number-sections --self-contained --toc-depth=2 --filter=pandoc-citeproc --output=./out/html/thesis.html
```

In the output, my TOC looks like this (and the generated HTML is the same).

```
1. Chapter 1
2. Chapter 2
  2.1 Chapter 2 Subsection 1
  2.2 Chapter 2 Subsection 2
  2.3 Chapter 2 Subsection 3
  2.4 Chapter 3 Subsection 1
  2.5 Chapter 3 Subsection 2
  2.6 Chapter 3 Subsection 3
3. Chapter 4
4. Chapter 5
```

In other words, the subsections of chapter 3 are being appended to chapter 2 and there is no top level chapter 3 section.

If I re-order the chapters in the command it renders correctly:

```
pandoc src/index.md src/frontmatter.md src/chapter-1.md src/chapter-3.md src/chapter-2.md src/chapter-4.md src/chapter-5.md src/bibliography.md --toc --number-sections --self-contained --toc-depth=2 --filter=pandoc-citeproc --output=./out/html/thesis.html
```

which generates:

```
1. Chapter 1
2. Chapter 3
  2.1 Chapter 3 Subsection 1
  2.2 Chapter 3 Subsection 2
  2.3 Chapter 3 Subsection 3
3. Chapter 2
  3.1 Chapter 2 Subsection 1
  3.2 Chapter 2 Subsection 2
  3.3 Chapter 2 Subsection 3
4. Chapter 4
5. Chapter 5
```

... which is correctly generated for the command I typed, with no sections missing, but of course is not the order I want.

Does anyone have any idea might be causing chapter 3 to render as part of chapter 2 when it comes after it in the ordering? Or any ideas how I can get more debug information to see why this is happening? I see no information or error or warning messages in the console.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Without the content of the src/chapter-2.md and src/chapter-3.md it is hard to tell what is wrong. As it is your thesis you probably cannot share this. What happens when you only  generate the 2 chapters? Probably best is that you reduce your files for the test and replace the text by dummy text, during the reduction you should regular build the docu so that you can see when the problem stops occurring.

Comment: Yeah I figure there must be some special character or pandoc syntax problem in that file, but I can't figure out why i'm not being given any errors? Is there some way to detect pandoc parse errors?

Comment: No idea as I don't use pandoc, but maybe the `--verbose` or `--log` options can share a light. Best is the tedious process of trying to reduce the problem.

Comment: Make sure that `chapter2.md` ends with a newline character. Pandoc uses multiple file by concatenating them together, inserting a single newline character between them. So if a file doesn't end with a newline, then this can lead to unexpected parsing of the input.

Comment: @tarleb Thank you, I think you are right, I think this may have been the issue. I managed to fix it myself, I had noticed that Chapter 2 ended with a footnote expansion. I moved the footnote expansion further up the document and that removed the issue, but perhaps all I needed to do was add the newline. i will check and report back.

Comment: @tarleb I just ran some tests, looks like I needed to have a newline at the end of the file AND have the footnote expansion be further up the file, it needs to finish with normal body text. A newline alone (or even 2) added at the end wasn't enough to fix it. How bizarre! But thanks for helping me with this!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @albert. You would expect those would help but I just ran some tests again and neither the log file nor the verbose output had anything useful. I guess the footnote and the chapter 3 heading combined to make something that it thought was valid markdown syntax, so no errors were generated. Just mentioning this in case anyone else hits a similar issue, log & verbose may not help!